# Cannot install openvas9 on Bionic for ARM

Tags: 18.04, arm, openvas

I am trying to install openvas (actually openvas9) on an Bionic on ARM.
Following the instructions from https://hackertarget.com/openvas-9-install-ubuntu-1604/ 
When trying to run the command :

`apt install openvas9`

returns :

```
E: Unable to locate package openvas9
```

Any idea ?

\T,

---

A bit further down the road 
It worked as a charm ... but doing a `/etc/init.d/openvas-scanner` after the install and an update (`greenbone-nvt-sync && greenbone-scapdata-sync  && greenbone-certdata-sync`), it fails to start.
Doing a check with the command `openvas-setup` also hangs on : 
`...
total size is 13  speedup is 0.09
(openvassd:32104): lib  kb_redis-CRITICAL **: 23:18:33.136: get_redis_ctx: redis connection error: Connection refused
(openvassd:32104): lib  kb_redis-CRITICAL **: 23:18:33.137: redis_new: cannot access redis at '/tmp/redis.sock'
(openvassd:32104): lib  kb_redis-CRITICAL **: 23:18:33.137: get_redis_ctx: redis connection error: Connection refused`

The redis socket seems to have the right rights : `root@scw-a2f9e9:~# ls -la /tmp/redis.sock 
srw-rw---- 1 root root 0 Sep 14 00:54 /tmp/redis.sock
root@scw-a2f9e9:~# file /tmp/redis.sock 
/tmp/redis.sock: socket`

Comment: your link fo xenial distribution, try this https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/openvas/9.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu!

According to the [official ubuntu package documentation](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/openvas), `openvas` is available (version 9.0.2) for 18.04 in the *universe* repository.

You should check (and eventually enable) if the universe repository is enable (`sudo add-apt-repository universe`) and then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openvas
```

Comment: It worked as a charm ... but doing a {{/etc/init.d/openvas-scanner}} after the install and an update ({{greenbone-nvt-sync && greenbone-scapdata-sync  && greenbone-certdata-sync}}), it fails to start.
Doing a check with the command {{openvas-setup}} also hangs on :